# What can I use to manage PWA(password agent) files?

Tags: software-recommendation

Our company has been moving from windows to Ubuntu ... Everything is wonderful ... but we have a database of passwords stored in Password agent ... and i do not now how to move the database password in Ubuntu ...(PWA file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Export the password in Password Agent as csv. Then import them in Ubuntu using Keepass.

http://keepass.info/features.html

Comment: tnx it works!!!!